# How can I make only one list item expand when a button is clicked in React (no hooks)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of students and I want to make an expandable list view. Basically each student will have a plus & minus button and every time it's clicked a list of all student's grades will expand. However, so far when I click on one of the buttons it opens all the students' grade lists at the same time.

I can't seem to figure out how I can fix this so that when I click on a specific student it will open only that student's grades. Can anyone help me on this? I think I'm close, but I can't get there!

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Average from './Average';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component{

  state = {
    students: [],
    error: null,
    search: null,
    open: false,
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (data) => {
        this.setState({ 
          students: data.students,
        })
      },
      (error) => {
        this.setState({ error });
      })
  }
  
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  }

  togglePanel = e => {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })
  }


  render(){
    let { search, students, open } = this.state;
    const display = students.filter((student) => {
      if(search == null)
        return student;
      else if(student.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || 
              student.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())){
        return student;
      }
    }).map((student, idx) => {
      return (
        <div className = "student-container" key = {student.id}>
          <img className = "student-pic" src = {student.pic} alt = "pictures"/>
          <div className = "student-mini">
            <h1>{student.firstName.toUpperCase()} {student.lastName.toUpperCase()}</h1>
            <p>Email: {student.email}</p>
            <p>Company: {student.company}</p>
            <p>Skill: {student.skill}</p>
            <Average grades = {student.grades}/>
            <button onClick = {(e) => this.togglePanel(e)}>{open ? '-' : '+'}</button>
            <div>
            <p>{open ? student.grades.map((grade, id) => {
                return (
                  <p key = {id}>Test {id + 1}: {grade}%</p>
                )
              }): null}
            </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    })

    return (
      <div className = "gray-container">
        <div className = "white-container">
          <form>
            <input onChange = {this.handleChange} type = "text" placeholder = "Search by 
             name">
            </input>
          </form>
          <div>
            {display}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The problem is that your state's `open` applies to the whole component, which is an array of `<div>`s. You can try to make a sub-component which represents a single student record and have the `open` state apply to this sub-component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your expandable panels uses the same single `open` state to determine whether it should be expanded or not, that is why they all open at once. The easiest solution here is for each panel to have its own state.

Ideally, you want to extract the JSX from your map's return statement to separate component presenting a single student's panel, let's say `StudentPanel`, pass the student object as prop and move the `open` state and the toggle function to that component as well.

UPDATE: You'd have something like this:

```
class StudentPanel extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false
  }

  togglePanel = e => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ open: !prevState.open }))
  }

  render() {
    const { student } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className = "student-container" key = {student.id}>
        // (...) rest of JSX
      </div>
    );  
  }
}
```

In `render` of your `App` you'd have:

```
(...).map(student => <StudentPanel student={student} />)
```

and the `open` property and `togglePanel` can be removed from `App` component completely.

Comment: How can I move the ```open``` state to the ```StudentPanel``` component?